# DuplicateTickets by it Start and Closed dates

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to expand a table between the created and closed dates (if there is no a Closed date them expand it to today's date*

This is the table (QUERY)

```
Ticket              Created                Closed              Brand
MAS-10772905    2021-06-15T14:00:00                             A
MAS-11542813    2021-06-10T16:00:00    2021-06-12T10:00:00      B
MAS-11850014    2021-06-12T16:00:00    2021-06-12T10:00:00      A
MAS-13926615    2021-06-08T16:00:00    2021-06-10T10:00:00      C
...
```

And this is what I want to get

```
   Ticket      Actived Date        Brand
MAS-10772905    2021-06-15           A
MAS-10772905    2021-06-16           A
MAS-10772905    2021-06-17           A
MAS-11542813    2021-06-10           B
MAS-11542813    2021-06-11           B
MAS-11542813    2021-06-12           B
MAS-11850014    2021-06-12           A
MAS-13926615    2021-06-08           C
MAS-13926615    2021-06-09           C
MAS-13926615    2021-06-10           C
...
```

I try to do it by this queries but is not working... boths gives me the following failed message: "Table name "CTE" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request."

```
WITH

QUERY AS (
    SELECT
    Ticket,
    Brand,
    Created,
    Closed
    FROM TABLE1
    ),

CTE AS (
    SELECT Ticket, Created, Created AS Closed, Brand FROM QUERY
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.Ticket, DATE_ADD(T1.Created, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS Created, 
        DATE_ADD(T1.Created, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS Created, T1.Brand
    FROM CTE T1
    JOIN QUERY T2 ON T1.Ticket = T2.Ticket
    WHERE T2.Closed > T1.Closed
)

SELECT Ticket, Created, Brand FROM CTE ORDER BY Ticket
```

And also try this one

```
WITH

QUERY AS (
    SELECT
    Ticket,
    Brand,
    Created,
    Closed
    ),

CTE AS (
    SELECT Ticket, Created, Brand, Closed FROM QUERY 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Ticket, DATE_ADD(T1.Created, INTERVAL 1 DAY) Brand, Closed
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Created < Closed
)

SELECT Ticket, Created, Brand FROM CTE 
ORDER BY Ticket, Created
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand dates like this, the easier solution is to use the `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` function as below:

```
SELECT
  Ticket,
  Active_date,
  Brand
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(EXTRACT(DATE
      FROM
        Created), EXTRACT(DATE
      FROM
        COALESCE(Closed,
          CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))) AS ActDate
  FROM
    sample) t,
  UNNEST(t.ActDate) Active_date
ORDER BY
  Brand,
  Ticket,
  Active_date
```

It gives you this kind of result:

[image]

Note: in the `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY`, the date array starts at `Created` and ends at `Closed` unless it is not closed yet, then the current date is used.